# Using Green DAO with content provider

Tags: android, database, orm, android-sqlite, greendao

I am planning to use `GreenDAO` in my project. I had already tested it by creating a test project. However, I have couple of requirements, which I need to fulfill.

1. Database of my app will be encrypted. To do so, we are planning to use [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/). I found this [link](https://github.com/ywenblocker/GreenDao-SQLCipher). I am studying it, but interested to know is there anything available in original GreenDAO project.
2. As my app will sync data to/from the server, I'll use [SyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html) as I don't want to do all heavylifting by myself which is already done by Android framework. But it requires `Content Provider` to work with. So, how can I use GreenDAO with `Content Provider`.

**Update 2**

My project has seven entities. I used `addContentProvider()` over entities. And seven different content providers are generated. Is there any way to have all sqlite tables in a single content provider?

Comment: I use greendao with syncAdapter. All you need to do is add .addContentProvider() while generating entity. Unfortunatelly, I do not have knowledge about 1st point.

Comment: @dominik4142 can you give me a little help using the generated content providers with the sync adapter? I'm learning how to use the sync adapter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a project running with greenDao and a content provider. First I was using [ProviGen](https://github.com/TimotheeJeannin/ProviGen) just to generate the content provider and query with the content resolver but then the project turned to be very large so I decided to implement greenDAO, what I did is to use the contentProvider  created in provigen to get the database from it, so now I have both the contentProvider and provigen attached to the same database. I encourage you to create your ContentProvider and attach your daoMaster to the database generated with it.  Here is the piece of code I used in the onCreate Application Class:

```
private static DaoSession daoSession;
public void onCreate(){
SQLiteOpenHelper myAppOpenHelper = new ProvigenContentProvider().openHelper(this); //ContentProvider created previously
SQLiteDatabase db = myAppOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
DaoMaster daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
}
```

after that to use greendao just :

```
public DaoSession getDaoSession(){
        return daoSession;
}
```

And there you can have both contentProvider and greenDao. If you have not started your project yet then create the content provider manually and create the DaoMaster with the same code in here. Good Luck

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I am looking to it. I have a small doubt. I am not clear what do I need to do if I need to query or insert using content provider's `query and insert` methods

Comment: Using content Provider you can simply `getContentResolver.query(String content_uri, String[] column_names, String where_clause, String[] where_parameters, String order); ` in any of the activities or if executed in a fragment use `getActivity.` before, with greendao is easier you just have to `myObject = session.getMyDao().queryBuilder().where(MyDao.Properties.Id.eq(1)).uniqueOrThrow();` you can get more docus [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html)

Comment: for the point 1 simply use the link you posted, i dont think greenDao have native sqlCipher support for now

Comment: For your update #2, yes you can have all your sqlite tables in a single content provider, just create them in the `onCreate()` method of the sqliteOpenHelper and save the CONTENT_URI then you can query them with getContentProvider and providing the proper contentURI. i REally recommend you using ProviGEN it will ease your work without making too much abstraction in your code.

Comment: I suspect that using GreenDAO with caching + updates/deletes coming from content provider may invalidate those objects stored in GreenDAO cache. Anyone knows how to deal with this?